# Integrating Sentry and Elastic APM in Buffalo

Tags: go, sentry, buffalo, elastic-apm

I am trying to integrate Elastic APM and Sentry into my website using Buffalo. The interesting files are as follows:

`handlers/sentryHandler.go`

```
package handlers

import (
    sentryhttp "github.com/getsentry/sentry-go/http"
    "github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo"
)

func SentryHandler(next buffalo.Handler) buffalo.Handler {
    handler := buffalo.WrapBuffaloHandler(next)
    sentryHandler := sentryhttp.New(sentryhttp.Options{})

    return buffalo.WrapHandler(sentryHandler.Handle(handler))
}
```

`handlers/elasticAPMHandler.go`

```
package handlers

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo"
    "go.elastic.co/apm/module/apmhttp"
)

func ElasticAPMHandler(next buffalo.Handler) buffalo.Handler {
    fmt.Println("AAA")
    handler := apmhttp.Wrap(buffalo.WrapBuffaloHandler(next))
    return buffalo.WrapHandler(handler)
}
```

`actions/app.go`

```
package actions

import (
    "github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo"
    "github.com/gobuffalo/envy"
    forcessl "github.com/gobuffalo/mw-forcessl"
    paramlogger "github.com/gobuffalo/mw-paramlogger"
    "github.com/unrolled/secure"

    "my_website/handlers"
    "my_website/models"

    "github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo-pop/pop/popmw"
    csrf "github.com/gobuffalo/mw-csrf"
    i18n "github.com/gobuffalo/mw-i18n"
    "github.com/gobuffalo/packr/v2"
)

func App() *buffalo.App {
    if app == nil {
        app = buffalo.New(buffalo.Options{
            Env:         ENV,
            SessionName: "_my_website_session",
        })

        // Automatically redirect to SSL
        app.Use(forceSSL())

        // Catch errors and send them to Sentry.
        app.Use(handlers.SentryHandler)

        // Get tracing information and send it to Elastic.
        app.Use(handlers.ElasticAPMHandler)

        // Other Buffalo middleware stuff goes here...

        // Routing stuff goes here...
    }

    return app
}
```

The problem I'm running into is if I have the Sentry/APM handlers at the top, then I get errors like `application.html: line 24: "showPagePath": unknown identifier`. However, if I move it to just before I set up the routes, then I get a no transaction found error. So, I'm guessing that the handler wrappers are dropping the `buffalo.Context` information. So, what would I need to do to be able to integrate Sentry and Elastic in Buffalo asides from trying to reimplement their wrappers?

Answer (score 0):

> So, I'm guessing that the handler wrappers are dropping the buffalo.Context information.

That's correct. The problem is that `buffalo.WrapHandler` ([Source](https://github.com/gobuffalo/buffalo/blob/bbdf70341bf44365b8fb0c83689ebe030ce76e5b/wrappers.go#L7-L12)) throws away all of the context other than the underlying `http.Request`/`http.Response`:

```
// WrapHandler wraps a standard http.Handler and transforms it
// into a buffalo.Handler.
func WrapHandler(h http.Handler) Handler {
    return func(c Context) error {
        h.ServeHTTP(c.Response(), c.Request())
        return nil
    }
}
```

> So, what would I need to do to be able to integrate Sentry and Elastic in Buffalo asides from trying to reimplement their wrappers?

I can see two options:

- Reimplement `buffalo.WrapHandler`/`buffalo.WrapBuffaloHandler` to stop throwing away the buffalo.Context. This would involve storing the `buffalo.Context` in the underlying `http.Request`'s context, and then pulling it out again on the other side instead of creating a whole new context.
- Implement Buffalo-specific middleware for Sentry and Elastic APM without using the `Wrap*` functions.

There's an open issue in the Elastic APM agent for the latter option: [elastic/apm#39](https://github.com/elastic/apm-agent-go/issues/39).